# transport_encoding error during installing with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, html5lib

I'm getting unexpected arg: keyword encoding in parse() while trying to install any python package through pip.

I'm getting this problem since i installed tensorflow for python 3.6, which probably led to some issue with html5lib and setuptools. Have reinstalled html5lib1.0b10 using tar.gz file (admin install) but the issue still remains. 
Please help!!

```
pip install spacy
Collecting spacy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue was indeed with html5lib and setuptools, I re-installed html5lib using

```
conda install -c anaconda html5lib
```

Although package versions were same, it said 'The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel', and installed conda, conda-env, html5lib. I'm unsure about higher-priority channel part. 
But this answered my problem!!

Answer (score 5):

Problem appears after installing `tensorflow 1.3.0`.

Reinstall `html5lib`.

```
conda uninstall html5lib --force
conda install html5lib
```

Solves the problem temporarily until next `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`.
Had the same problem with `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` as well.