# pip doesn't upgrade in windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-3.6, miniconda

Even though there were some similar question but none of proposed solution applied to my case. Simply, after `tensorflow` installationattempting to install packages this message

```
"You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available. You   
should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' 
command."
```

like this:
[image]
But following this `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` doesn't work even with administrator level, nor this one : `python -m pip install -U pip`.

(I'm using Miniconda, just as an additional information)

Comment: What error message do you get with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`? It usually gives no trouble.

Comment: (The nuclear option is of course uninstall+reinstall the latest distribution incl. pip. But that's a last resort. Did you install conda as Administrator or User?)

Comment: I had installed conda as User. I put the image of when I tried to upgrade as admimstrator (just to try), but as normal user also the situation is the same.

Comment: Rather than using an image to show the error code, it's better to copy the full error code and add it to the question as code. It's easier for us to copy, and it's better for search engines and other users to find relevant results.

Comment: not-working reply code was already above the image.

Comment: its simply pip install pip --upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem after installing tensorflow in windows.
pip install wasn't working for me. pip install returned same error.

After some checks, i found that issue was with html5lib and setuptools. I have answered the same here [transport_encoding solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528671/transport-encoding-error-during-installing-with-pip/46529204#46529204)

Basically, i reinstalled html5lib using

```
conda install -c anaconda html5lib
```

which were superseded by a higher priority channel

Answer (score 2):

I think it manybe PIP command before installing `TensorFlow` can be normal use, only after installation problems, probably because the new version of Python compatible with TensorFlow might be a little less, so update PIP and conda command, can fix. by command `conda install pip`

Comment: @Hamidreza Ok,Sorry I didn't see that.I think you should check whether the python status is normal by command python -v .And then I suggest you reinstall python.

Comment: well, I ran `python -v`,  everything seems to be ok, on the other hand I'm using it with lots of library now, so I hope I can find a solution.

Comment: I think it manybe PIP command before installing TensorFlow can be normal use, only after installation problems, probably because the new version of Python compatible with TensorFlow might be a little less, so update PIP and conda command, can fix.                      by command 'conda install pip'

Comment: you are right, it raised right after tesorflow installation, but I did not know that. thanks @Leal.li

Comment: `'conda install pip` worked and I didn't loss already installed packages :)

Answer (score 1):

@Hamidreza, use this command`pip install --upgrade pip`

If it is not working, try this as alternate `easy_install pip`
I hope it works

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip` doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: Try reinstalling the pip.

Comment: `pip install pip --upgrade` gets the work done note: you are running cmd as administrator

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked in Conda-environments for a long time but I think it was:

```
conda update pip
```

Answer (score 1):

After much wailing and gnashing of teeth, I found the answer [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pip).

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pip
```

Sample Output:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0      --> 2018.4.16-0       conda-forge
    certifi:         2018.4.16-py36_0  --> 2018.4.16-py36_0  conda-forge
    conda:           4.5.9-py36_0      --> 4.5.9-py36_0      conda-forge
    openssl:         1.0.2o-hfa6e2cd_1 --> 1.0.2o-hfa6e2cd_1 conda-forge
    pip:             10.0.1-py36_0     --> 18.0-py36_1       conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages ca-certificates-2018 |  176 KB |
############################################################################## | 100% openssl-1.0.2o       |  5.4 MB |
############################################################################## | 100% conda-4.5.9          |  654 KB |
############################################################################## | 100% certifi-2018.4.16    |  143 KB |
############################################################################## | 100% pip-18.0             |  1.8 MB |
############################################################################## | 100% Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done Executing transaction: done

(base) C:\Users\User-pc>pip --version pip 18.0 from C:\dev\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
```